# Some programs open and close immediately-Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, computer-behavior

My PC suddenly doesn't open some programs when I double-click on them. I used Task Manager to check if the program runs in the background after double-clicking,and it does get listed under 'Processes' for a short moment and disappears.

Programs that are not opening: 
[CodeBlocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) and [Xamarin Studio](https://www.xamarin.com/studio).

Programs that open:
Eclipse,Cygwin,RStudio,NetBeans,Python,Google Chrome,MS Word Excel,VLC.

I've rebooted multiple times and also tried to 'Run as administrator'. That didn't help.

However,both programs run perfectly if machine is rebooted in Safe Mode.

Thanks.

Comment: It would really help if you tell us which programs open and which ones dont so we can find common ground to these programs.

Comment: I strongly suggest you repair the installations to these programs.  This problem is normally caused by not having a require library installed.

Comment: @LPChip Thanks for the urgent reply.I've edited my question to include the programs that open and not opening.

Comment: @Ramhound How do I repair their installations?

Comment: You can try to start the programs via **CONSOLE / CMD**. Maybe you get some helpful output.

Comment: Disregard the suggestion, based on the larger list, my suggestion won't work.  I strongly suspect you have some major system corruption going on though.

Comment: Did you try using System Restore to restore your computer to a point when the programs were working?

Comment: @Atoadaso I already tried System Restore.

Comment: @Ben i'm not getting any output on CMD.

Comment: @Atoadaso I'll keep trying different restore dates and check if it helps.

Comment: @Ramhound's suggestion could be the case.  There are only two programs not opening.  Repairing both seems like a sensible idea.  Repairing is often done by the installer/uninstaller, as a slightly faster process than a full uninstallation.  How to do it: Get the installer files/disc(s) handy in case they are needed.  Try running the uninstaller, and see if there is an option to repair.  For some software, the way to repair is to run the installer instead (and running the uninstaller will proceed to uninstall).  Though uninstalling/reinstalling may  not be a bad thing to do either.

Comment: @TOOGAM Reinstalling didn't help,but when I run the machine in safe mode,both programs run perfectly.

Comment: @Jay - That means you have conflicting software installed.  Use a program like Autoruns to determine what software that is precisely.

Comment: More than likely it is a recent driver update, do you remember any just before the problem started?

Comment: The problem was being caused by the anti-virus program.I went to the settings and put those programs under 'Exclusions' and 'Allow'.All issues solved.Programs are running ok. Thanks for all the assistance.Cheers!

Comment: @Jay: Consider posting an answer.  That will help others with a similar problem.

Comment: @fixer1234 Sure.Done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was being caused by the anti-virus program.
I went to the settings and put those programs under 'Exclusions' and 'Allow'.This excludes those specific programs from being scanned,unless I manually scan them.

Before changing the settings of the anti-virus,I rebooted the machine in 'Safe Mode' and ran the programs to test if they would run without any issues,which they did.

So all issues solved.Programs are now running ok.

Hopefully this will help others.